# Problem while submitting app update on google play store

Tags: android

i have an app on play store and when i submitted an update i got an email that it has been rejected due to policy violation because of an issue with the ads of the app. I fixed the issue and uploaded a new update yet after 8 days both versions are showing "in review".There is not a mention of the issue on the google play console or a way to cancel that version and keep only the new one from what i see. Any ideas how to solve this issue? Its an app bundle made with flutter.

Answer (score 0):

In review means that google is checking it for something, maybe malware, maybe breaking the google policy etc. Its best if you contact google and ask why.